# How to authorize only Anonymous to log in (ASP.NET 5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Actually i'm working on a web-app in Asp.NET 5 and I'm looking for a solution that only Anonymous can have access to the LOGIN and REGISTER page.

If you have ideas ..

Comment: You can create a custom authorize attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code To Know the user is authenticated or not:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
      Response.Redirect("/Home");
}
```